# If div is visible, than show that content in other div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a possible way to do this? I am not friendly with jQuery, and i dont have a clue how to do this properly.

I made [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y88F6/) demo.

I have two div classes. One is hidden, and other is visible. How to add hidden div to visible div, and make hidden div visible in visible div? I mean, that if hidden div has content, than both data should be visible in visible div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content-hidden">hidden content</div>

<div class="content-visible">visible content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-hidden { float:left; width:100px; height:100px; background:red; display:none; }

.content-visible { float:left; width:100px; height:100px; background:blue; }
```

**jQuery**

```
if($('.content-visible').is(':visible')) {
    // i dont know what to do next
}
```

Sorry for bad english, and thanks for any answers!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AMeLL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly. You can try

```
if($('.content-visible').is(':visible')) {
    $('.content-hidden').show().appendTo('.content-visible')
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AMeLL/)

References

1. [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
2. [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: All the answers was similar, and i think that all would work fine. I tested this one, and it worked just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Except that it completely fails to meet the requirement you specify "*if hidden div has content*," which is perhaps a translation problem. Still, it's good you found your answer!

Comment: Perhaps it was a translation problem.. sorry. But it worked just fine. I am mixing this script with php select query, and it worked just fine. Thanks again to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest:

```
// select the element(s) by the class-name:
$('.content-hidden')
    // append the element(s) found by that selector to the specified element:
    .appendTo('.content-visible')
    // make the element(s) visible:
    .show();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Y88F6/4/).

Otherwise, you can do much the same, but toggle the `content-hidden` and `content-visible` classes to make the moved `div` visible:

```
$('.content-hidden').appendTo('.content-visible')
    // replaces the class-names currently used in the element(s),
    // with the ones not currently used:
    .toggleClass('content-hidden content-visible');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Y88F6/7/).

Edited to add the check to ensure the element has contents before appending/moving/showing:

```
// selecting element(s) by the class-name,
$('.content-hidden')
    // filtering that collection:
    .filter(function(){
        // keeping only those elements for whom the expression returns true
        // (or a truthy value):
               // working on the current-element in the collection:
        return $(this)
                   // getting its contents (childNodes):
                   .contents()
                   // filtering those childNodes:
                   .filter(function(){
                       // again, keeping only those that evaluate to true/truthy:
                              // it has a nodeType:
                       return this.nodeType && 
                              // and that nodeType is either 1 (an element) or 3 (a textNode):
                              (this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 3);
    }).length;
})
    // appending those retained elements to the '.content-visible' element:
    .appendTo('.content-visible')
    // making them visible by toggling class-names:
    .toggleClass('content-visible content-hidden');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Y88F6/9/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** to display the hidden content:

```
if($('.content-visible').is(':visible')) {
    $('.content-hidden').show();
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y88F6/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.content-visible').is(':visible')) {
    $('.content-visible').append($('.content-hidden').html());
}
```